# Suming up Rows Based On Repetition Of Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

> I Don't Know Why My Previous Topic Was Marked!!!???
>
> This Is What I've Done So Far. I Can't Think Of Anything Else.

[image]

> So Many Things I've Done To Reach To This Point Which Is Illustrated In **My Problem** Section. Which For Simplification I Made Name A,B,C,... .**I'm Not Giving You My Homework.**

**My Problem:**

[image]

Comment: Oops, I cant copy the Query Text! :(

Comment: That Query Is Just For People Who Say This Is My HomeWork. Forget It. My Problem Starts From **"My Problem"** Section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SQL for SqlServer 2008 to solve your problem.

```
with data as (select name, count(*) as occurrence, sum(value) as sumvalue from mytab group by name)
select * from data where
  occurrence=(select max(occurrence) from data)
  and sumvalue=(select max(sumvalue) from data data2 where data2.occurrence=data.occurrence)
```

In **data** the needed values are collected (sum and count). Now we select the rows with max occurrence and filtering out the rows with the max value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56b00/4

Comment: Clever Answer - God Help You - Thank You Very Very Much

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Name], [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Count] DESC, Value DESC) [rn]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Name], SUM(Value) [Value], COUNT(1) [Count]
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY Name
    ) t
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c8bc/2)

or more simply

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [Name], [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT [Name], SUM(Value) [Value], COUNT(1) [Count]
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Name
) t
ORDER BY [Count] DESC, Value DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d478a/3)